# Create a seqential table from another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table in my SQL Server database:

```
Product      Week       Units      Exta units effective     Extra units
A515      2014-01-11      51          2014-01-25              23.24
A515      2014-01-11      51          2014-01-11              25.86
A515      2014-01-18      52          2014-01-25              23.24
A515      2014-01-18      52          2014-01-11              25.86
A515      2014-01-25      50          2014-01-25              23.24
A515      2014-01-25      50          2014-01-11              25.86
A515      2014-02-01      45          2014-01-25              23.24
A515      2014-02-01      45          2014-01-11              25.86
```

The values in the  `week` and `units` columns repeats which i don't want. The duplicate records should be deleted. I want the `extra units effective` column to start at the earliest date corresponding to the `week` column. Basicly i want a table from the above table that look like this,

```
Product       Week    Units      Exta units effective      Extra units
A515       2014-01-11   51          2014-01-11                25.86
A515       2014-01-18   52          2014-01-11                25.86
A515       2014-01-25   50          2014-01-25                23.24
A515       2014-02-01   45          2014-01-25                23.24
```

I thought about building a query table from the original table to create the last table but i am not sure how. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How do you choose 2014-01-25 for the week of 2014-02-01.  The earliest date for that column is 2014-01-11.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I've taken "the earliest date corresponding to the week column" as "the earliest date that's not earlier than the week column", but I agree the phrasing could use some work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a slightly more complex use of [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and a CTE seem to be in order:

```
;With Ordered as (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Week,Units
                                ORDER BY
                CASE WHEN [Exta units effective] >= Week THEN 0
                     ELSE 1 END,
                [Exta units effective]) as rn
    FROM [Unknown Table]
)
select * from Ordered where rn = 1
```

Normally this would just be an `ORDER BY` in the `ROW_NUMBER()` expression to select the earliest date for each `Week` and `Units` combiation, but I see that we need to exclude any `[Exta units effective]` which pre-date the `Week` value so I've added a `CASE` expression to filter those to the end of the row numbering.

Comment: +1 . . . Contingent on your interpretation of the question being correct.  (I *do* see how it could mean this.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `row_number()`, which assigns a sequential value within each group ordered by the date you want.  Then just choose the first one:

```
select product, week, units, extraunitseffective, extraunits
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by product, week order by extraunitseffective) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I thought so too at first, but they want the rows dated `-01-25` for the weeks `-01-25` and `-02-01`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select` and `into` for this. Something like the following should get you there:

```
SELECT 
max(Product) as Product,
Week,
Units,
min([Extra units effective]) as 'Extra units effective',
max([Extra units]) as 'Extra units'
INTO Some_Other_Table
FROM Original_Table
GROUP BY Week, Units
```

You may need to play with the `select` query a bit to make sure it's returning the results you really want. Also, spaces in column names frequently trip me up, so make sure the square braces and single quotes are correct as well.

Comment: Given that all of the sample rows consist of pairs where they both have an entry dated `2014-01-11` with extra units of `23.24`, and one dated `2014-01-25` with extra units of `25.86`, *and* the fact that all four of those values appear in the desired results, it should be clear that neither `min()` nor `max()` is suitable for computing the results here.